# Using Power Mock for Unit testing in Android Framework

Tags: android, mocking, powermock

I have been trying to Unit test in Android using PowerMock and Mockito. I am successful in mocking through Mockito, but since Mockito cannot mock Static methods and final classes , So I need to include PowerMock along with Mockito.

But whenever I use the line

```
Example ma=PowerMockito.mock(Example.class);
```

It is giving Exception:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyCla(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:110)
```

What am I doing Wrong. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you using mockito with android?

Comment: I have included its jar.
Example a=mock(Example.class) is working properly and is not giving any exception

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows that you cannot merely include mockito into an android test project.
http://www.paulbutcher.com/2012/05/mockito-on-android-step-by-step/

If you must use mocking frameworks, either follow steps in that or use something like the robolectric framework.

Comment: As of mockito 1.9.5 released 10/12, this is no longer true. You can use mockito on android but you have to include a few extra jars. Here is a tutorial for setting it up from square http://corner.squareup.com/2012/10/mockito-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the @PrepareForTest(Example.class) annotation to the top of your test class?